# No desktop after installing gnome shell

Tags: unity

Two days ago,I've tried to install gnome on Ubuntu 14.04 using this command:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop

after that everything has been working well.But I've noticed that there is no folder in the desktop,also I cannot do "right-clic" on the desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you (or GNOME) have disabled icons on the desktop. The fastest way to re-enable them is using GNOME Tweak Tool.
You can install it by running:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

After that, run the tweak tool and, from the "Desktop" tab, turn "Icons on Desktop" ON:
[image: GNOME Tweak Tool - Desktop tab]